# MySQL datafiles on SMB3 network storage

Tags: mysql, innodb, storage

We have MySQL-server on Ubuntu with InnoDB-datafiles on a local disk. As part of an upgrade program, the company is planning to put the datafiles on a Windows fileserver where they can be mounted with SMB3.

Is it a good idea to put the InnoDB-files on a network share or is it better to keep them on a local disk?

Comment: *Is it a good idea to put the InnoDB-files on a network share* No. Study carefully [Creating a Tablespace Outside of the Data Directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tablespace-placing.html) - you will see this is a very risky venture.

Comment: Ok, that helps! We will keep our InnoDB-files on a local disk if that's more reliable (and performant). Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

NO!  MySQL is not designed to allow two servers to access the same databases.

Or, maybe...

If your goal is to provide redundancy for the case of server failure, then *maybe* you could set up a *non-running* MySQL on a secondary server, ready to mount the disk subsystem in the case of failure.

Consider, instead, Clustering (Galera, PXC, InnoDB Cluster).

Comment: We do not plan to share the datafiles between servers, that wouldn't last more than a second :). I was just wondering if the InnoDB-files would be better off on the network or on a local disk. For disaster recovery we will maintain a master/slave setup.

Comment: There are pros and cons of local network storage.  You probably will not see any performance difference unless you are working at the limits of the drive.